# Print values from linked list with start value as a default value in a function

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I am trying to make a recursion function that will print all the elements in a linked list backward.

This is the function that I have made:

```
void lista::printBack(node *pocetak) {
    if (pocetak==NULL) {
        return ;
    }    
    printBack(pocetak->sljedeci);
    cout<<pocetak->podatak<<" ";
}
```

Now for the question. I want to set default value of the parameter pocetak, so that the function can print the list without the start value.

But when I do this:

```
void lista::printBack(node *pocetak = head) 
{
    if (pocetak==NULL) {
        return ;
    }

    printBack(pocetak->sljedeci);

    cout<<pocetak->podatak<<" ";
}
```

I always get a error message:
     main.cpp:17:19: error: no matching function for call to ‘lista::printBack()’
     main.cpp:17:19: note: candidate is:
     lista.h:20:10: note: void lista::printBack(node*)
     lista.h:20:10: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

Is that any way I can do this? Thank you.

Comment: Did you change the prototype? The default argument should go in the prototype only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the default argument in the header file (the implementation `lista::printBack(node* pocetak=head)` is not enough)

```
// lista.h
struct node;
node* head;

struct lista
{
  void printBack(node* pocetak=head);
};
```

Note that this means you will need to have a valid `node* head` declared before the `lista` type is defined, the best way for which is t use forward declaration (see above).  Also, `head` will be a global variable, which is usually not a good idea.

EDIT: fixed type names

Comment: I have updated my answer after realizing that `printBack()` is a member of `lista`, not `node`